# RVIZ Could not find font Liberation Sans in MovableText::setFontName

Tags: exception, ros, ogre

I am using **ROS melodic** on **archlinux** with the following environment settings:

```
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/melodic/etc/ros
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=2
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/melodic/share
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
ROS_DISTRO=melodic
```

And the font file exists in`/opt/ros/melodic/share/rviz/ogre_media/fonts/liberation_sans.fontdef`

**PROBLEM**:
`rviz` works OK with the first tutorial example `roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=/opt/ros/melodic/share/urdf_tutorial/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf`, but when I use model with any joint it throws the following error:

> terminate called after throwing an
>   instance of 'Ogre::Exception'
>   what():  : Could not find font
>   Liberation Sans in
>   MovableText::setFontName

for example :
when I run:`roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=/opt/ros/melodic/share/urdf_tutorial/urdf/02-multipleshapes.urdf` it signals the previous error, but when I comment the joint section, it works well.

**Questions**:

- Can I change the search path for ogre to solve that?
- How can I solve this error?

NOTE:
I have reinstalled rviz.
I am using archlinux.

```
[ INFO] [1535655892.425579750]: rviz version 1.13.1
[ INFO] [1535655892.425678114]: compiled against Qt version 5.11.1
[ INFO] [1535655892.425738813]: compiled against OGRE version 1.11.1 (Rhagorthua)
```

Comment: I can generate your error under Ubuntu 18.04 by just renaming the file, but everthing else works just fine. I can only think about the `OGRE_HOME` variable has either been not or wrongly set during build. Its hard to say if the error comes with OGRE or Rviz. Have you tried an example application with plain OGRE?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with ogre 1.11 new API.

I have reinstalled rviz using https://github.com/ProfFan/rviz commits.

He has a pull-request here https://github.com/fizyr-forks/rviz/pull/1

And it's working now.